# Change of code if Database is changed (form Access to SQL Server)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to migrate from Access Database to SQL server database.  Do I need to make changes (for saving, reading, deleting etc. data) to my code as well?

I understand I need to change connection but what about code?

Thanks

Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, Access SQL Queries are very similar to SQL Server Queries. Therefore, unless you're using Access-specific constructs such as `Val`, `CInt`, etc in your queries, you can safely migrate to SQL Server.

It is recommended though, that you thoroughly test the program after migration lest you run into 'strange' errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the conversion will require some time and troubleshooting.  For one, Access through version 2007 uses VBA for the back-end code and SQL Server's programming is quite different from VBA.  Developer's transitioning from Visual Basic 6 (very similar to VBA) to VB.NET ran into quite a few challenges.

Also, keep in mind that SQL Server is best used as the back-end storage engine.  The user interface is typically written in a .NET language using Visual Studio.  SQL Server (at least through 2005 -- I haven't used 2008) doesn't have user interface components like a File Open dialog box.